# How to define Object Key as String Type

Tags: typescript

Below is the function signature,

```
export function getVideoBooleansParamsString(videoBooleans: {
  string: { label: string; value: boolean }
}): string {}
```

And this is the `arg` I am trying to pass into,

```
const videoBooleans = { video: { label: 'video', value: true } }
```

And it produce the following error,

```
(63,33): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ exchange: { filterType: string; filterValues: string[]; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{string: FilterModel; }'.
  Property 'string' is missing in type '{ exchange: { filterType: string; filterValues: string[]; }; }'.
```

What I intend to declare is an object whatever the key is has the content of `{ label: string; value: boolean }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have it defined now expects the following:

```
const videoBooleans = { string: { label: 'video', value: true } };

getVideoBooleansParamsString(videoBooleans);
```

You can define it like this, if you want the key to be any string:

```
export function getVideoBooleansParamsString(videoBooleans: {
  [key: string]: { label: string; value: boolean }
}): string { }
```

Or like this, to be more specific:

```
export function getVideoBooleansParamsString(videoBooleans: {
  video: { label: string; value: boolean }
}): string { }
```

You can also define an interface, which can make the function signature a bit cleaner:

```
interface MyVideoType {
   [key: string]: { label: string, value: true };
}

export function getVideoBooleansParamsString(videoBooleans: MyVideoType): string { }

const video: MyVideoType = { video: { label: 'video', value: true } };

getVideoBooleansParamsString(video);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define an index for your parameter type :

```
export function getVideoBooleansParamsString(videoBooleans: {
  [name :string] : { label: string; value: boolean }
}): string {}
```